# Tensorflow with sycl with fpga acceleration

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, opencl, fpga, sycl

So I need to have some form of low latency hardware acceleration for 
Tensorflow inferencing on a `raspberry-pi`. I looked into using leflow but it cannot support large `tensorflow` models on small `FPGAs`.

I have figured out how to build `tensorflow` from source with sycl support. Where I am getting stuck though is on how to configure sycl (or OpenCL which `sycl` wraps) to work with an fpga.

I am also not sure how to physically wire my fpga to the raspis gpios such that it accelerates `opencl`.

Any help, or links regarding this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Using ComputeCpp, an implementation of SYCL, you can only target devices that provide driver support for SPIR OpenCL or SPIR-V. You can check if a device is supported by copying the ComputeCpp binaries onto the device then executing the "computecpp_info" tool (in the bin folder). This will output what hardware is detected and if there is SPIR/SPIR-V support.

Comment: What FPGA do you want to use? Does it support OpenCL 1.2 with SPIR-V? That’s a requirement for the SYCL compilers I know about that support FPGAs. Also, to run well on an FPGA, the code needs to be written for an FPGA, not a GPU. I think TensorFlow SYCL targets GPUs.